# Adding Three.JS 'OrbitControls' Causes Black-Screen in VueJS application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, vuetify.js

I have been working through the basic cube exercise on **Three.js**, integrating the three.js cube into my **Vue.JS application**.

All was well, my cube rotated as planned using animate etc.

However, it all falls apart when I add **OrbitControls**.
I have tried three different versions of npm package: three-orbitcontrols, three-orbit-controls(THREE) and now orbit-controls-es6.

Regardless of which one I use, as soon as I remove comments in front of:
`controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)` my screen canvas goes black...

I have included my code below so you can see what I have.
I've spent hours testing and searching today, but to no avail.

Hope someone can shine some light on my error.

Thanks all!

```
<template>
    <div id="container"></div>
</template>

<script> 
import * as Three from "three";
import OrbitControls from 'orbit-controls-es6';

export default {
  name: 'ThreeWindow',
  data() {
    return {
      camera: null,
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      mesh: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
        let container = document.getElementById('container');

        this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(70, container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight, 0.01, 10);
        this.camera.position.z = 1;

        this.scene = new Three.Scene();

        let geometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
        let material = new Three.MeshNormalMaterial();

        this.mesh = new Three.Mesh(geometry, material);
        this.scene.add(this.mesh);

        //var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
       //This line here breaks the code and sends canvas black with no cube.

        this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
        container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    },
    animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        //controls.update();
        this.mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.init();
      this.animate();
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    #container {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
    }
</style>




[Cube Image Provided.][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwEEi.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the previous answer, import orbit controls as follows - worked for me:

```
import * as Three from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

But you have some other errors that are breaking it:

As you are working with a `VueComponent` object, you need to modify your `camera` and `renderer` variables that you pass in to the `OrbitControls` constructor with the `this` reference, so they are referring to the variables attached to your component,

So you need to replace

```
var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

with

```
this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
```

and move that line below the line where you declare the `this.renderer`

so you end up with:

```
this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});

this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
```

then similarly in your `animate()` function,

replace `controls.update()` with `this.controls.update()`

Answer (score 1):

you should import OrbitControl as below:

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check for errors in the browser console.
The first thing that pops out to me is the second argument you are sending to the OrbitControls constructor is `renderer.domElement`, but the renderer object is created after this line.
Try moving the OrbitControls call to after the renderer is created.
ie.

```
this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement); /*<-- moved to after renderer is created*/
```

I was [experimenting with Three.js and Vue](https://github.com/2pha/vue-three-shaders) a couple of years back, You may find it interesting or helpful