# ThreeJs black screen in VueJs application

Tags: vue.js, three.js

I have been studying some basics of Three.js into
a Vue.JS application.

I am following a tutorial and the code is the same as the original autor.
A cube geometry was added as a initial test, but my screen canvas goes black, and since i'm new to vuejs I can't find the error.

See some of the code below..

thank you all!

```js
<template>
  <div id="space">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

export default {
  name: "space",
 
  data() {
    return {
    
      scene: null,
      camera: null,
      renderer: null,
      controls: null,

      iR: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let that = this;

    this.Awake();

    
    window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);

    function onWindowResize() {
      that.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      that.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      that.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    onWindowResize();
  },
  methods: {
    Awake() {
      let container = document.getElementById("container");

     
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
      this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x222222);

     
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        25,
        window.clientWidth / window.clientHeight,
        1,
        100
      );
 
      this.camera.position.set(8, 4, 0);

    
      this.iR = new THREE.Group();
      this.iR = "Interactive Root";
      this.scene.add(this.iR);

    
      let light0 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xfafafa, 0.25);

      let light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xfafafa, 0.4);
      light1.position.set(200, 90, 40);

      let light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xfafafa, 0.4);
      light2.position.set(200, 90, -40);

      this.scene.add(light0);
      this.scene.add(light1);
      this.scene.add(light2);

    
      let gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(
        60,
        150,
        new THREE.Color(0x555555),
        new THREE.Color(0x333333)
      );
      this.scene.add(gridHelper);

      //mesh geometry to test
      let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
      let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
      let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      this.scene.add(mesh);

      
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
      this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      
      this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

      
      container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

      
      this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
      this.controls.enableDamping = true;
      this.controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
      this.controls.screenSpacePanning = false;
      this.controls.maxDistance = 800;

      this.controls.update();

      this.Update();
      this.GetGeoJson();
    },

    
    Update() {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.Update);

      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      this.controls.update();
    },

    GetGeoJson() {
      fetch("./assets/ufpe.geojson").then((res) => {
        res.json().then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          //this.LoadBuildings(data)
        });
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>



<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59019379/adding-three-js-orbitcontrols-causes-black-screen-in-vuejs-application

Comment: Strange. I don't see anything obviously wrong with this code without running it. Nothing in the console?  It might be that the small camera fov and the camera's position.x make it that there's nothing in view of the camera. But you should at least see the scene's background color, right? What happens when, after adding the mesh, you add this.camera.lookAt( mesh.position ); ? Also, is the Update function actually firing?